# How to close screen while moving to next screen in android platform?

Tags: android

How to close screen while moving to next screen in android platform?

i have one working scenario like this. while moving from one screen to other screen need to close(i shouldn't show screen while press Esc key).

Please help me

Regards,
Jeyavel N

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that by "screen" you mean "Activity".

All you need to do is call finish() after you call startActivity().  eg.:

```
startActivity( new Intent( this, Foo.class) );
finish();
```

That should do it.